# How to use optiontype as FILE in Rundeck options

Tags: python, api, input, rundeck

My Python Code is working fine for API request where option type as Text, delimited by Comma(,) for some set of input values.

I want to use same approach where option type is FILE, where each input value contains new rows.

In usage , i can see below options, please let me know which below option to be used in my code when i am trying to upload a file in runtime?

````
Commandline Arguments: ${file.Serial_Number}
Script Content: @file.Serial_Number@
The original file name:
Bash: $RD_FILE_SERIAL_NUMBER_FILENAME
Commandline Arguments: ${file.Serial_Number.fileName}
Script Content: @file.Serial_Number.fileName@
The file content SHA-256 value:
Bash: $RD_FILE_SERIAL_NUMBER_SHA
Commandline Arguments: ${file.Serial_Number.sha}
Script Content: @file.Serial_Number.sha@```
````

Answer (score 1):

I leave a job definition example, you can check how to get the content, the filename, and the path:

Python script:

```py
import os

# content
os.system('cat @file.myfile@')

print("\n")

print("file name:")
print ("@file.myfile.fileName@\n")

print("file path:")
print("@file.myfile@")
```

Job Definition:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='myfile' type='file' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>b1d6e1e1-15e9-40c6-b6a9-317f31910fd0</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>PythonTEST</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.py</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[import os

# content
os.system('cat @file.myfile@')

print("\n")

print("file name:")
print ("@file.myfile.fileName@\n")

print("file path:")
print("@file.myfile@")
]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/usr/bin/python3</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>b1d6e1e1-15e9-40c6-b6a9-317f31910fd0</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Example file "lipsum":

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNxl6.jpg) the result.